# Appcelerator iOS Module for Firebase Push notification (cloud messaging)

Tags: ios, google-cloud-messaging, appcelerator, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to you FCM for push notification for appcelerator ios and android app.
For android there seems to be module https://github.com/caffeinalab/ti.goosh

But I haven't find any module for iOS. Anyone used FCM with appcelerator iOS App ?